# Computing the intersection of two arithmetic sequences $(a\mathbb{Z} + b) \cap (c \mathbb{Z} + d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am getting stuck writing a general formula for the intersection of two arithmetic sequences.

$$ (a\mathbb{Z} + b) \cap (c \mathbb{Z} + d) = \begin{cases} 
\varnothing & \text{if ???} \\
?\mathbb{Z} + ? & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

For any two arithmetic sequences, I would know how to compute their (possibly null) intersection, but I don't know how to write a formula in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are effectively asking for solutions to the equation: 
$$aX - c Y = d -b$$ 
this has solutions if and only if $\gcd(a,c)\mid d-b$. 
If it has a solution you can find it using the Euclidean Algorithm.

Once you have one solution $(x_0,y_0)$, then the intersection is $(ax_0 + b)+ \operatorname{lcm}(a,c) \mathbb{Z}$.

There is no very direct way to "write down" a solution $(x_0,y_0)$; but using modular inverses you could come close.

Answer (score 5):

Two arithmetic sequences $a\mathbb{Z}+b$ and $c\mathbb{Z}+d$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$ intersect nontrivially if and only if $\gcd(a,c)$ divides $b-d$, in which case $$(a\mathbb{Z}+b)\cap(c\mathbb{Z}+d)=\text{lcm}(a,c)\mathbb{Z}+r\,,$$
where $r$ is the unique solution modulo $\text{lcm}(a,c)$ to the system of congruence $r\equiv b\pmod{a}$ and $r\equiv d\pmod{c}$.  To be fair, this is precisely a rephrasing of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

To prove the first claim, let $t:=\gcd(a,c)$.  If $(a\mathbb{Z}+b)\cap (c\mathbb{Z}+d)\neq \emptyset$, then suppose $s$ is in the intersection.  Therefore, $ax+b=s=cy+d$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.    Thus, $-ax+cy=b-d$, so $t\mid (b-d)$, as $t\mid a$ and $t\mid c$.
Conversely, suppose $t\mid b-d$.  Then, there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b-d=-ax+cy$, so $ax+b=cy+d$.  Hence, $a\mathbb{Z}+b$ and $c\mathbb{Z}+d$ have a common element.

Now, we shall prove the second claim.  Let $m:=\text{lcm}(a,c)$.  Clearly, every element of $P:=(a\mathbb{Z}+b)\cap(c\mathbb{Z}+d)$ is congruent to $r$ modulo $m$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  We claim that every such number is indeed in $P$.  Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $r\equiv b\pmod{a}$ and $r\equiv d\pmod{c}$, we have $r=ax+b$ and $r=cy+d$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Now, $km+r=a\left(x+k\frac{m}{a}\right)+b$ and $km+r=c\left(y+k\frac{m}{c}\right)+d$ with $x+k\frac{m}{a},y+k\frac{m}{c}\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore, $km+r\in P$, and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 4):

This is like solving the Diophantine equation
$$ax+b=cy+d$$
which is
$$ax-cy=d-b$$

This equation has solutions if and only if $\gcd(a,c)$ divides $d-b$. If this condition holds, there are infinitely many solutions. The intersection of the arithmetic progressions is empty or infinite, and if it is infinite it is also an arithmetic progression.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations).

Answer (score 0):

It amounts to solving the system of simultaneous congruences:
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv b\mod a\\x\equiv d\mod c
\end{cases}$$
This system has a solution idf and only if $b\equiv d\mod  \gcd(a,c)$, and it is unique modulo $\operatorname{lcm}(a,c)$.